# Set default terminal in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I've set the default terminal using `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` but every time I press Control + Alt + T, it still opens up gnome-terminal.

I would like to change it to terminator if possible :-).

If it helps, I'm on Gnome Classic.

Answer (score 12):

The reason why your keyboard is opening gnome-terminal instead of terminator is because the keyboard shortcut is explicitly mapped to gnome-terminal and not the default terminal.

So, you can try remapping your keyboard shortcut to point to terminator instead of gnome-terminal.

Search for *Keyboard* in the dash overview and go to *Shortcuts* tab. Then move to *Custom Shortcuts* and add a new entry with the command pointing to `x-terminal-emulator` and reassign the shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]

[(Reference)](https://askubuntu.com/a/132825/25798)

Comment: Hi jokerdino, I just tried it on Gnome and it works fine.  I think it's a problem with Gnome Classic - would you know how to fix that?  Cheers Chris

Comment: I just tried these exact instructions in Gnome-Classic and its good for me. Cheers